# Python misidentification of int values

Tags: python, math, factorial

I have been for some time writing a function which relies on many other to return an answer. When I finished it, it stated I had wrongly used the "*" somewhere. I went through everything and could not see a problem. I finally found that it was because of a simple factorial function earlier defined, as shown below:

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
elif n < 0 or (type(float)):
    print "%s is an invalid input; Positive integer value is required" % (n)
else:
    return (n)*fact(n-1)
```

However if I enter n = 6, it returns that 6 is a floating number, and thus exits the rest of the function, and I hope someone can answer why this is happening and how to get around it.

Many Thanks

Comment: `type(float)` returns a type, so it's always true

Answer (score 4):

```
elif n < 0 or (type(float)):
```

Even when `n >= 0`, `(type(float))` part will return the `type` of `float` and that is non-empty or Truthy value. So, the condition will be met always. What you need is, `isinstance`

```
elif n < 0 or isinstance(n, float):
```

But I would suggest,

```
elif not isinstance(n, int) or n < 0:
```

Now, if `n` is anything other than an `int` the error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your second condition should be `isinstance(n, float)`:

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
elif n < 0 or isinstance(n, float):
    print "%s is an invalid input; Positive integer value is required" % (n)
else:
    return (n)*fact(n-1)
```

Indeed, as you can see below, [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) check the type and the [built-in `type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) returns a type:

```
>>> isinstance(1.0, float)
True
>>> isinstance(1, float)
False
>>> type(float)
<type 'type'>
```

Comment: Yep, that's done it, thank you. And thank you for the quick respone