# Why doesn't the != operator in python work for type the function (or is it just my code)?

Tags: python, string, variables

I want to provide my code before asking the question for some context.

My code:

```
a = float(input('Insert the value for a: '))
b = float(input('Insert the value for b: '))
c = float(input('Insert the value for c: '))
if type(a) != (float() or int()):
print ('You didn\'t insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!')
sleep(1)
print (a)
if type(b) != (float() or int()):
print ('You didn\'t insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!')
sleep(1)
print (b)
if type(c) != (float() or int()):
print ('You didn\'t insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!')
sleep(1)
print (c)
```

This outputs (given that I input values):

Insert the value for a: 8

Insert the value for b: 3

Insert the value for c: 2

You didn't insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!

8.0

You didn't insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!

3.0

You didn't insert a number! Try again! This is your last chance or I will stop running!

2.0

The problem is I specified that if it isn't a float or an integer, it should deliver the message. But I did insert an integer, but it still printed out the string. What's the problem? Can you assign variables to types of numbers?

Comment: When you add the parentheses for `float()` and execute it by itself, you'll notice it returns as `0.0` You should just check it against `float` and `int`. Also, you're trying to cast the input to a float, so it will error out even if it's not a number. Instead you should use the string method `isdigit()`

Comment: @GreenCell: You really shouldn't use `isdigit()`; there are so many different ways to enter legal `float`s that any hand-rolled "check before conversion" function is likely to exclude valid values, allow invalid ones, or both. This is why you use the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) pattern: Just *do* the conversion, and catch the `ValueError` if it occurs. The `float` constructor knows what is valid, let it do its job, rather than trying to [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl), reimplementing the `float` checking poorly.

Answer (score 6):

You called the `float` and `int` constructors, which, with no arguments, return the zero value.

So:

```
if type(a) != (float() or int()):
```

translates to:

```
if type(a) != (0.0 or 0):
```

which then (thanks to boolean evaluation rules) becomes:

```
if type(a) != 0:
```

which is clearly wrong.

If you want to test for precise types, check with `in` on a `tuple` of the types, e.g.:

```
if type(a) not in (float, int):
```

Normally you *want* to accept subclasses though, so the Pythonic approach would be:

```
if not isinstance(a, (float, int)):
```

Of course, none of this will actually solve your problem of checking. You explicitly created `a` by converting a `str` to a `float`. It's *always* going to be a `float`, or it's going to raise a `ValueError` if the string isn't a legal `float` value. The type checking will never help.

So what you *really* want is to perform the conversion in a `try` block and catch the exception if it fails:

```
try:
    a = float(input('Insert the value for a: '))
    b = float(input('Insert the value for b: '))
    c = float(input('Insert the value for c: '))
except ValueError:
    sys.exit('You didn\'t insert a number!')  # or some equivalent action to handle failure
```

If you want to loop until they give you a valid number, [we have several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22025764/364696) [questions to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/364696) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15099379/364696) (there are dozens more, I just can't be bothered to link them all).

Comment: Oh! That makes sense! Why do you say if not isinstance? Doesn't that imply that it isn't that type?

Comment: @user10059620: Your test appeared to be looking for things that are neither `float` nor `int`. `isinstance(a, (float, int))` returns `True` if `a` *is* a `float` or an `int`, so to match your original logic, you'd need to invert the logic; "if 'a' is not a float or an int, complain" would be the English description of `if not isinstance(a, (float, int)): print(errormessage)`

Answer (score 2):

You want to do:

```
if type(...) not in (float, int):
```

Because need `in` operator for this, and no calling

Better:

```
if not isinstance(var,(float,int)):
```

Or inefficient way:

```
if type(...) is not float and type(...) is not int:
```

You can also do:

```
import sys
try:
    a = float(input('Insert the value for a: '))
    b = float(input('Insert the value for b: '))
    c = float(input('Insert the value for c: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Error: Not a integer or float') 
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: `(float or int)` evaluates to `float`, which is not iterable. I assume you meant `(float, int)`?

Comment: Also `and` rather than `or`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks a lot for catching my stupid mistake, I did the edit, still it's ineffiecient

Answer (score 1):

`!=` works fine; the problem is that `a != (b or c)` does not mean `a != b or a != c`: `!=` does not distribute over `or`. It has nothing to do with types.

Answer (score 0):

Its printing exactly what you are asking it to print

```
a = 1 

if a != 1 or a!=2:
    print('Of course, a != 2 is True!')
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 insert.py
> Of course, a != 2 is True!
> ```

Only one of the `or` statements needs to evaluate to `True` for the `if` statement to execute, and since `float != int` it becomes `True` and runs `print` as you asked it to do